# Shell script - trim file name

Tags: linux, shell, sh, filenames, trim

I have very basic knowledge in shell script.I need your help to solve this. 
Requirement is my file name - CA_Trigger_BAOSFeed_240615062341.zip
output I need - "CA_Trigger_BAOSFeed_" and also
I want to remove the timestamp from the file name and append this timestamp 250615072235 dynamically using shell script

Can you please share your knowledge on this.

Comment: What shell? Windows, cmd.exe comand.com, or som eunix shell?

Comment: its unix shell script Andre

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial to achieve with power of `sed` and reqular expressions:

```
$ echo 'CA_Trigger_BAOSFeed_240615062341.zip' | sed 's|[0-9]\+|250615072235|'
CA_Trigger_BAOSFeed_250615072235.zip
```

Here, I replaced (first occurence of) numbers in filename by string `250615072235`.